# Why is Oracle not treating '' as NULL in a BETWEEN with NVL comparison

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this query, not filling in any data as the variables. Expecting a row; I get nothing.

```
select 1 from dual
where  SYSDATE BETWEEN NVL(:START_DATE, SYSDATE) AND NVL(:END_DATE, SYSDATE)
```

I try this, expecting a row, and I get a row.

```
select 1 from dual
where  SYSDATE BETWEEN SYSDATE  AND  SYSDATE
```

Something is not working as expected. An NVL should treat '' as NULL.

I try this, expecting a row, and I get a row.

```
select 1 from dual
where '' is null
```

If '' IS NULL, which we have now proven, this should return a row. But it's not.

```
select 1 from dual
where SYSDATE BETWEEN NVL('', SYSDATE) AND NVL('', SYSDATE)
```

Comment: I'm sorry - perhaps I missed something. Where in your first statement did you have `''`? Also - `''` is not *always* the same as NULL. Consider what happens when you assign `''` to a CHAR variable. Hmmm... :-)

Comment: When you ran your test, what front-end (client interface) program did you use? In particular, neither SQL\*Plus nor SQL Developer support the DATE data type for bind variables. If you pass in `null` it is interpreted as null string. How would you pass in dates that are NOT null with that code you have? Pass in strings and hope that the NLS_DATE_FORMAT is just right? I bet if you were able to pass actual DATE data type you would get the expected result - but you can't do that in SQL\*Plus or SQL Developer.

Comment: You've certainly demonstrated that SQL (or at least Oracle's implementation) is not composable.

Comment: I'm using TOAD as the developer tool, and APEX as is what this statement is going into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some interesting answers here, but I'm not sure anyone has yet explained quite why your query returns no rows.  (Apologies if they have and I missed it - just ignore me then!)

It is because `NVL('', SYSDATE)` is returning a **character string**, since the first argument '' is a character strng.  So `NVL('', SYSDATE)` is equivalent to `NVL('', TO_CHAR(SYSDATE))`.  And since we haven't specified the format for the TO_CHAR, Oracle will use the default which usually doesn't include a time component.

So this:

```
where SYSDATE BETWEEN NVL(:START_DATE, SYSDATE) AND NVL(:END_DATE, SYSDATE)
```

Is being treated somethinlg like this:

```
where SYSDATE BETWEEN '25-APR-2020' AND '25-APR-2020'
```

Oracle will then convert those strings back into dates to perform the BETWEEN, so will assume 00:00:00 for the time of day.  Therefore unless you run this at exactly midnight, it will not return a row.

However, if you set your default date format to include the time like this:

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS';
```

You will find it now works, because the time component of the date no longer gets lost in the implicit conversions.

Probably the best way to deal with this though is to ensure you are dealing with dates and not strings at all:

```
select 1 from dual
where  SYSDATE BETWEEN NVL(TO_DATE(:START_DATE), SYSDATE)
                   AND NVL(TO_DATE(:END_DATE), SYSDATE)
```

Answer (score 1):

It ain't what you don't know that'll kill you. It's "what you know" that just ain't so...

The reason that Oracle isn't treating `''` as NULL is because `''` is not a NULL - it's a zero-length string constant. Now, right here people are going to jump in and tell me I'm wrong, and that I don't know what I'm talking about, and question my parentage, and probably start a petition to deny my Social Security and kick me out of the Old Farts Home, but I'm right. Here's a demonstration:

```
DECLARE
  vStr  VARCHAR2(10) := '';
  cStr  CHAR(10) := '';
  vNULL VARCHAR2(10) := NULL;
  cNULL CHAR(10) := NULL;
  nStr  NUMBER := '';
  nNULL NUMBER := NULL;
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('LENGTH(vStr)  = ' || LENGTH(vStr));
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('LENGTH(cStr)  = ' || LENGTH(cStr));

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('LENGTH(vNULL) = ' || LENGTH(vNULL));
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('LENGTH(cNULL) = ' || LENGTH(cNULL));

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('LENGTH(nStr)  = ' || LENGTH(nStr));
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('LENGTH(nNULL) = ' || LENGTH(nNULL));
END;
```

Now **without looking down below** (yes, I know - it's hard. Try... :-) what output do you expect from the code above? If you're like most people (including me, until I tripped over this a few years ago) you'd expect it to be:

```
LENGTH(vStr)  = 
LENGTH(cStr)  = 
LENGTH(vNULL) = 
LENGTH(cNULL) = 
LENGTH(nStr)  = 
LENGTH(nNULL) =
```

That is, you'd expect the `LENGTH` function to return NULL when applied to all those variables - because they should all be NULL, right?

But that's not what you get ([see this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3ebc110fda482562a229ab76a07cdff0)). What you *actually* get is:

```
LENGTH(vStr)  = 
LENGTH(cStr)  = 10
LENGTH(vNULL) = 
LENGTH(cNULL) = 
LENGTH(nStr)  = 
LENGTH(nNULL) =
```

Whoa! Wait!! What's that `10` doing in there?!?

Well, it's pretty simple. Think about the semantics of the `CHAR` data type in PL/SQL. If you assign a string to a `CHAR` variable or field, and the length of the string assigned is shorter than the defined length of the variable or field, the value assigned to the variable or field is padded on the right to the full defined width of the variable/field - in this case, 10 characters. So when a `''` - that is, a zero-length string constant - is assigned to the variable `cStr`, the value assigned to the variable is padded on the right to the defined width of the variable, so `cStr` ends up filled with 10 blanks. But when a NULL is assigned to that same character variable it ends up being set to NULL, as expected, and the `LENGTH` function returns NULL, as expected.

The semantics of VARCHAR2 (and, for the moment, VARCHAR - at least until Oracle gets around to supporting ANSI semantics for VARCHAR - which they're going to do Real Soon Now (tm)) are different in Oracle. When a variable/field of type VARCHAR2 is assigned a value it doesn't do any padding; instead, it assigns only the significant characters of the source string to the variable or field, and if the resultant length of the string assigned to the variable is zero then the variable or field is set to NULL, in accordance with the Oracle rule that "zero-length string values are the same as NULL". But this happens at the time that the value is assigned to the variable. `''` on its own is still a zero-length string constant.

Just remember - it ain't what you don't know that'll kill you. It's "what you know" that just ain't so... :-)

Comment: Very long explanation that has absolutely nothing to do with the OP's question. His question was 100% in the SQL context. Your demo is PL/SQL. In plain SQL, `select length(cast('' as char(10))) from dual;` returns `null`, not `10`. And, in any case, an answer along these lines should first state that - very likely - the OP is not passing in a `null` **date** to the query, but some other data type.

Comment: There are, by the way, very simple, direct ways in which plain Oracle SQL treats `''` as an empty string, not as true `null` - perhaps the simplest example is the treatment in concatenation.

Comment: As stated in my original question, [select 1 from dual where '' is null] returns a row. So oracle is treating '' as null in this respect.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that some user interfaces (including, annoyingly, SQL*Plus and SQL Developer) don't support the DATE data type for bind variables.

This is a limitation of those user interfaces. Oracle SQL is perfectly capable of working with DATE bind variables, and if you are able to pass to it NULL of data type DATE, it will process that as expected. See an illustration below.

Some answers, posted already, deal with the secondary issue - if you pass in NULL of data type CHAR or VARCHAR2, what happens? I don't think understanding the precise reason is important; what **is** exceptionally important is to understand this limitation of front-end programs, and - if you are forced to use them to interact with the database - make sure your bind variables are string data type, and the query reflects that (by using TO_DATE with proper date format model).

If you are using PL/SQL, and/or perhaps other calling environments (not sure about ApEx for example, since I don't use it), you **can** pass in NULL of DATE data type directly, and get the expected behavior. Here is an illustration: I build your query as a dynamic query, with bind variables, and I invoke it and pass to it NULL of data type DATE. Look what happens:

```
declare
  l_sql clob;
  l_n   number;
begin
  l_sql := 'select 1 
            from   dual 
            where  sysdate between nvl(:start_date, sysdate)
                               and nvl(:end_date  , sysdate)';
  execute immediate l_sql into l_n using cast(null as date), cast(null as date);
  dbms_output.put_line(l_n);
end;
/


1

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use like the below to match null with null to get a row

```
select 1 from dual
where nvl('',SYSDATE) BETWEEN NVL('', SYSDATE) AND NVL('', SYSDATE)
```

Comment: This answer doesn't include the :start_date or :end_date